# Click on link with "i" and "span" inside issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

Our team use google tag manager (or something like this) to track what phone number or button user will click. This tool requires elements to have `id`.

When we click on a simple link, without `<i>` or `<span>` in it, everything is ok. We get the `id`, the link works, the popup with "call" or "cancel" appears.

However, it's not that simple with markdown below:

```
<a class="phone-number" id="phone2" href="tel:+380671112233">
  <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>+38 067 111 22 33</span>
</a>
```

Link works, the popup appears, but **the `id` is not tracked**

I used jQuery to `console.log` what element has been clicked. It appears that click actually has been made on `<span>` or `<i>`. So my guess is that click event made on `<span>` or `<i>`, then bubbling thing happens and it triggers link. So popup appears as the link has been triggered, but click has been made on another element, so google tag manager can't catch id.

What can I do to disable click on inner elements and force click on `<a>` tag?

Comment: `a * { pointer-events: none }`

Comment: @ChrisG, no, this will dissable link.

Comment: How so? It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5yzf9oqw/ `a *` applies to elements *inside* the `<a>`, not the `<a>` itself.

Comment: Oh, my bad, i've missed "*" part. Will test your answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try to set "Click triggers" to "Just links" in GTM settings?

Reference: [Capturing The Correct Element In Google Tag Manager](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/capturing-the-correct-element-in-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: Hm seems like an answer to me. I'll send this to manager lol. Thanks, if this will help i'll mark your answer as correct little bit later